# Using as.Date returns mostly NAs, but some correct dates

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, as.date

I am trying to convert date information from a .csv file to date format in R, so that I create two week intervals with which to categorize data. However, when using as.Date, it is only working correctly on some of the dates, and leaving the rest as NA. I have tried editing the format of the date cells in excel, I have tried rewriting every single date cell in excel from scratch. I have tried changing my locale. I have tried everything I can find as a possible solution online. Please help!

```
    > lions <- read.csv("Lions_30m.csv")
    > dates<-as.character(lions$Date)
    > typeof(dates)
    [1] "character"
    > dates
     [1] "5/1/2017"  "5/9/2017"  "5/21/2017" "4/17/2017" "4/21/2017" "5/12/2017" 
    "3/27/2017" "3/13/2017"
     [9] "4/10/2017" "4/26/2017" "4/23/2017" "3/7/2017"  "5/28/2017" "4/27/2017" 
    "5/16/2017" "4/5/2017" 
    [17] "2/16/2017" "2/18/2017" "4/26/2017" "2/26/2017" "2/26/2017" "5/18/2017" 
    "3/4/2017"  "4/14/2017"
    [25] "3/3/2017"  "3/31/2017" "3/11/2017" "3/19/2017" "3/22/2017" "3/23/2017" 
    "3/25/2017" "4/13/2017"
    [33] "4/14/2017" "4/15/2017" "4/17/2017" "4/19/2017" "4/23/2017" "4/29/2017" 
    "5/15/2017" "3/26/2017"
    [41] "5/6/2017" 
    > date <-as.Date(dates, format='%d/%m/%Y')
    > date
    [1] "2017-01-05" "2017-09-05" NA           NA           NA           "2017-12-05" NA          
    [8] NA           "2017-10-04" NA           NA           "2017-07-03" NA           NA          
    [15] NA           "2017-05-04" NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
    [22] NA           "2017-04-03" NA           "2017-03-03" NA           "2017-11-03" NA          
    [29] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
    [36] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           "2017-06-05"
```

Comment: shouldn't be as.Date(dates,format ='%m/%d/%Y')?

Comment: Without knowing `Lions_30m.csv` it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `%m/%d/%Y`, not `%d/%m/%Y`, unless you live in a weird country where each year has 21 months....

Comment: It's amazing how easily stuff like that can be overlooked. I could have sworn I was so careful when I wrote that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this automatically with `anytime` that picks up the format based on the input

```
library(anytime)
anydate(c("4/26/2017", "2/26/2017", "2/26/2017" ))
#[1] "2017-04-26" "2017-02-26" "2017-02-26"
```

Comment: I am surprised to see you suggest a _package_ solution. I took you for a basic R advocate.

Comment: @EricFail  I don't have any bias for a specific category i.e.no packages/packages or `dplyr/data.table` or softwares `R/python/java` - anything that solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
dates  <- c("5/1/2017", "5/9/2017", "5/21/2017", "4/17/2017", "4/21/2017", "5/12/2017",
           "3/27/2017", "3/13/2017", "4/10/2017", "4/26/2017", "4/23/2017", "3/7/2017",
           "5/28/2017", "4/27/2017", "5/16/2017", "4/5/2017", "2/16/2017", "2/18/2017",
           "4/26/2017", "2/26/2017", "2/26/2017", "5/18/2017", "3/4/2017", "4/14/2017",
           "3/3/2017", "3/31/2017", "3/11/2017", "3/19/2017", "3/22/2017", "3/23/2017",
           "3/25/2017", "4/13/2017", "4/14/2017", "4/15/2017", "4/17/2017", "4/19/2017",
           "4/23/2017", "4/29/2017", "5/15/2017", "3/26/2017", "5/6/2017")
```

use `class()` to see what is it, so t speak

```
class(dates)
#> [1] "character"

as_date_dates <- as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%Y") 
class(as_date_dates)
#> [1] "Date"
```

or the [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate) way to avoid the `%m/%d/%Y`-`%d/%m/%Y` confusion. [Kinda same idea akrun is going with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166083/1305688),

```
# install.packages(c("lubridate"), dependencies = TRUE) 
library(lubridate)
as_lubridate_dates <- mdy(dates)
class(as_lubridate_dates)
#> [1] "Date"
```